# Предотвращение удаления SerialPort сборщиком мусора

Tags: c#

Имеется COM-порт с подключенным gprs модемом. Порт отправляет модему команду на установление связи (ATDT ) после чего модем уже сам устанавливает связь на своем аппаратном номере. Проблема в том, что связь устанавливается достаточно долго, и к моменту прихода ответа модема (CONNECT или NO CARRIER) забытый всеми СОМ порт успевает удалить сборщик мусора.
Необходимо сделать так, чтобы ссылка на порт не удалялась до команды. Поиск в интернете в качестве решения предлагает переопределение IDisposible. Подскажите, как это сделать в данной ситуации.

Comment: Сделать переменную serialPort статической либо долгоживущей. Почему её удаляет сборщик? Как у вас устроен код?

Comment: Имеется два списка - список портов и список телефонных номеров. В дух циклах выбирается вначале свободный порт, потом - свободный номер. Далее следует звонок на этот номер..

Comment: @VasyaM3 Вам про Фому (Сделать переменную serialPort статической либо долгоживущей.), а вы про Ерему (Имеется два списка...). Как осуществляется работа с портом? Покажите код работы с COM портом.

Comment: Код стандартный. Он слишком большой, чтобы прямо его привести. Порт открывается и подписывается на port_DataReceived. Потом осуществляется инициализация модема и обработка поступающих оттуда сообщений. Все это происходит асинхронно в методе await в отдельном потоке. Причина "глюков" определена, я о ней написал. Остается выяснить как от этой проблемы избавиться.. Поскольку все делается в отдельном потоке, статическая переменная здесь не подойдет.

Comment: @VasyaM3, для каждого соединения вам нужно создать отдельный serialPort и хранить ссылку на него вплоть до команды отбоя. Можно и через dispose, не суть важно.